# Why did my browser cant connect to nodejs socket.io server?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

My server side code is as below:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)


app.listen(1000);

function handler (req, res) {

  function (err, data) {

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('message', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

My browser side code is as below:

`window.WebSocket = window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket;`

```
if (!window.WebSocket){  

alert("WebSocket not supported by this browser");

return;

}

var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:1000/");

websocket.onmessage = function(evt){

var data = evt.data;
console.log(data);

}
```

First I run server with 'node server.js', it's ok. And when I run the cient code,browser said it couldnt connect to '`http://127.0.0.1:1000`' , why?
Do client side must write with socket.io too?

Answer (score 1):

yes you must talk with the right protocol to socket.io , look at [socket.io-client](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client) and the examples in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should connect to the server with socket.io client like this:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
</script>
```

You might want to checkout my [Scalable Socket.IO Sample](https://github.com/trantorLiu/Scalable-Socket.IO-Sample).

Comment: Hi, I know the client can be written like this. But I wonder if the client can be written without using socket.io.

Comment: I don't know either. Maybe you should trace the source code of socket.io client and understand it's protocol.

Comment: Why you want to connect to server without socket.io client? If you want to use only webscoket for transports, you can use the following  configuration on the server: `io.set('transports', ['websocket']);`.

Comment: I added this code.But it's not ok. Same problem happended. Because a html5 framework i'm using uses the browser websocket object.